# Badge to promote upvotes?

Tags: feature-request, up-votes, badge-request

So I was thinking about it today, there's an amazing lack of (up)votes on here and I think it shouldn't be like that so, don't know if this has already been tried or not but what about creating a badge to promote upvotes?

It would work like this:

You need to be the first to upvote a question who later got x upvotes (something like 10-15) and got +x views. I know there's also a problem here, there may be a bunch of random upvotes but just a suggestion to see what you think.

Comment: Where I spend my time, on EL&U, the problem isn't so much one of *not enough upvotes*, but *not enough upvotable questions*. That is, questions which are (a) non-trivial and (b) interesting to people other than OP.

Comment: "*I know there's also a problem here, there may be a bunch of random upvotes but just a suggestion to see what you think.*" you have mentioned the best disadvantage of this feature request.

Answer (score 6):

No, more up votes on questions are not needed.

The best reward for the OP asking a good question are useful answers and comments, not reputation points.

More up votes are not needed for the community moderation to work either, especially when you consider neither voting up nor down is also a choice:

- Vote down on bad questions.
- Vote up the rare well written and interesting questions.
- Neutral: You don't need to vote up every question that you don't vote down on.

Any proposed scheme to promote voting up also implicitly rewards people for asking *more questions*, not necessarily *better questions*. And I would say with the number of questions (often mediocre and sadly even too many good ones) that already remain open, the last thing we need is even more questions...

Answer (score 3):

I guess such a badge would do more harm than good. There are already badges that encourage upvotes, like Suffrage and Vox Populi. Those badges have the net effect that often the entire frontpage gets a single upvote. Even the worse questions get an vote, just to get those badges.

Encouraging users to be the first to vote on a post means actually encouraging users to post on any post and hope that post gets enough votes. That is a bad idea.

The current badges are more than enough to encourage upvotes. It is better to find a way to make other users more active on the site and care more for good content. The votes will come in eventually.